# Ubuntu 18.04 Intel Wireless-AC 3165 unreachable

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, network-manager, intel

I tried to install Ubuntu 18.04 on my Trekstor Surfbook A13B. Everything is working fine apart from the WiFi connection: No WiFi adapter is found. In Windows everything is working fine. A Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165 chip is installed. How can I get it up and running in Ubuntu? I really tried a lot, but nothing worked out. This is my Kernel Version: 4.20.0-042000-generic and you can find the wireless-info below

Thanks for your help!

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 26 Dec 2018 10:42 CET +0100

Booted last: 26 Dec 2018 00:00 CET +0100

Script from: 22 Oct 2018 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.20.0-042000-generic #201812232030 SMP Mon Dec 24 01:32:58 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=1

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf line 8: ignoring bad line starting with '“options'

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:8153 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 058f:5608 Alcor Micro Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### secure boot #######################

SecureBoot disabled

##### lsmod #############################

##### interfaces ########################

[/etc/network/interfaces]
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
    inet 192.168.2.147/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>
       valid_lft 1209280sec preferred_lft 1209280sec
    inet6 fe80::9f11:f2c1:e1ed:c6b3/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>  no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

default via 192.168.2.1 dev enx<IF from MAC [IF1]> proto dhcp metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enx<IF from MAC [IF1]> scope link metric 1000 
192.168.2.0/24 dev enx<IF from MAC [IF1]> proto kernel scope link src 192.168.2.147 metric 100 

##### resolv.conf #######################

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf']

nameserver 127.0.0.53

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

NetworkManager
    Wicd

Running:

root       896     1  0 10:36 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        USB 10/100/1000 LAN
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8152
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 v1.09.9
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/net/enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       d0efc44c-cd11-3be9-b5c7-fc821087ecec
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     100 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.2.147/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.2.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.2.1, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 192.168.2.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.2.1
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        dhcp_rebinding_time = 1058400
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        expiry = 1547026645
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        next_server = 192.168.2.1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       domain_name_servers = 192.168.2.1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 1209600
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       ip_address = 192.168.2.147
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       dhcp_renewal_time = 604800
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       routers = 192.168.2.1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       broadcast_address = 192.168.2.255
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       network_number = 192.168.2.0
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[29]:                       dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.2.1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::9f11:f2c1:e1ed:c6b3/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = ff00::/8, nh = ::, mt = 256, table=255
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 256
IP6.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 100
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{1}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   d0efc44c-cd11-3be9-b5c7-fc821087ecec | Wired connection 1

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:wwan

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf]]
[connectivity]
uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com/

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-mac-addr-change-wifi]
match-device=driver:rtl8723bs,driver:rtl8189es,driver:r8188eu,driver:8188eu,driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
wifi.cloned-mac-address=preserve
ethernet.cloned-mac-address=preserve

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### Netplan config ####################

[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/Berlin (based on set time zone)

global
country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>  no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>  Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

##### module parameters #################

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist ssb
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmfmac
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
“options iwlwifi disable_msix=1”

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[   60.590368] r8152 2-2:1.0 eth0: v1.09.9
[   60.632827] r8152 2-2:1.0 enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>: renamed from eth0
[   60.670407] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>: link is not ready (repeated 2 times)
[   72.246949] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>: link becomes ready
[   72.249484] r8152 2-2:1.0 enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>: carrier on
[  393.790297] iwlwifi-stack-public:master:7471:b7580da0

########## wireless info END ############
```

[EDIT]

```
$ sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwl


[   79.554570] Loading modules backported from iwlwifi
[   79.554570] iwlwifi-stack-public:master:7471:b7580da0
```

[EDIT]

```
    lspci -nnk | grep 8086
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:31f0] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:7270]
00:00.1 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Dynamic Platform and Thermal Framework Processor Participant [8086:318c] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:7270]
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:3185] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2212]
00:0e.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:3198] (rev 03)
00:0f.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Trusted Execution Engine Interface [8086:319a] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:7270]
00:12.0 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:31e3] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:7270]
00:13.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:31d8] (rev f3)
00:15.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:31a8] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:7270]
00:16.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Serial IO I2C Host Controller [8086:31ac] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:7270]
00:16.1 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Serial IO I2C Host Controller [8086:31ae] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:7270]
00:16.2 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:31b0] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:7270]
00:16.3 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:31b2] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:7270]
00:17.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:31b4] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:7270]
00:17.1 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:31b6] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:7270]
00:17.2 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:31b8] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:7270]
00:17.3 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:31ba] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:7270]
00:18.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Serial IO UART Host Controller [8086:31bc] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:7270]
00:18.1 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Serial IO UART Host Controller [8086:31be] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:7270]
00:18.2 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Serial IO UART Host Controller [8086:31c0] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:7270]
00:18.3 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Serial IO UART Host Controller [8086:31ee] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:7270]
00:19.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Serial IO SPI Host Controller [8086:31c2] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:7270]
00:19.1 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Serial IO SPI Host Controller [8086:31c4] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:7270]
00:19.2 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Serial IO SPI Host Controller [8086:31c6] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:7270]
00:1c.0 SD Host controller [0805]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:31cc] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:7270]
00:1e.0 SD Host controller [0805]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:31d0] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:7270]
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:31e8] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:7270]
00:1f.1 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Gaussian Mixture Model [8086:31d4] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:7270]
```

[EDIT]
No output on `dmesg | grep -i sdio`

Windows configuration

[Windows device manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLBFs.png)

[Intel 3165](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glKbD.png)

[EDIT]

```
dmesg | grep -i error
[    2.776933] RAS: Correctable Errors collector initialized.
[   16.498113] EXT4-fs (dm-0): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
```

Answer (score 0):

We see this in your wireless info:

```
[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
“options iwlwifi disable_msix=1”
```

The final line is mal-formed and must be removed:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

Remove the final line:

```
“options iwlwifi disable_msix=1”
```

Save (Ctrl+o followed by Enter) and exit (Ctrl+x) the text editor.

It also appears that you incorrectly installed a Broadcom driver; let's remove it:

```
sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Reboot and then edit your question to show the result of:

```
sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwl
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. I followed your instructions and posted the results

Comment: Now does lspci work? `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3`

Comment: No, there's no output after executing the command

Comment: But there's no error anymore

Comment: Please let us see: `lspci -nnk | grep 8086` Also, is there a setting in the BIOS to enable/disable wireless?

Comment: I added it to the post. No, there's no such option in the BIOS. And the WiFi is still working on Windows. I installed Ubuntu on a second drive

Comment: I still see no wireless. Please tell us exactly what Windows says about it. Also, post: `dmesg | grep -i sdio`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, This command doesn't return any output. And I added two screenshots of the windows device manager.

Comment: We wonder if there is a PCI bus or ACPI error: `dmesg | grep -i error` Is the BIOS set to defaults? If not, please try it. Very mysterious problem here.

Comment: I looked in the BIOS but I couldn't find any options like that. I added the output of your question to my post.

Comment: Nothing like this? https://i2.wp.com/neosmart.net/wiki/wp-content/uploads/sites/5/2015/03/reset-bios-1.jpg In many BIOS, F9 sets defaults.

Comment: I tried to set it to default, but it didn't work either

Comment: I regret that I have no other suggestions. Sorry.